# How to access method from the child component in parent in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I want to access the method in parent component and the method is present in child component. I tried using mixins. But the function is returning null instead of value. If i try to emit the object and that is working fine in parent component. How can I access the child method in parent other in vue3 Options API

Parent.vue

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mixins: [HelloWorld],
  methods: {
    fetchval(){
      let x = this.getVal();
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  dat(){
    let val!: string;
    return{
      val,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.val as string;
      },
      set(newval) {
        val = newval;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
   getVal(){
     return this.value as string;
   }
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Mixin is basically a chunk of defined logic, stored in a particular file. By just adding mixin to a component you just get all the mixin code in that component. So using mixin you can share same method that are defined in mixin to multiple components but you can't share one component's method to another component. You have to use emit or any another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to rethink the control flow, so that it have a clear separation of concern

- A parent should not directly access child's method. If the method should be invoked via a button click, then the child can process the click and emit the event back to parent callabck handler. For details, check [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)
- You may also check out state management, it can achieve what you want. Doc [Link](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html)

Having said that, declaring a component in the parent and also include that component in parent's mixin doesn't seem common, and may not be a good practice.

Just a quick answer, there might be more way to achieve what you desire.